# How to use SQL LIKE statement and filter results that are too similar in MYSQL or PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

So I am using queries like the following to search for songs but the 'blackbird' part is user input and can change.

```
SELECT * FROM song_table WHERE artistName LIKE '%blackbird%' OR 
songTitle LIKE '%blackbird%' LIMIT 10
```

I am getting results like:

```
{
"data":
[
    {
        "songTitle": "Blackbird",
        "artistName": "The Beatles",
    },
    {
        "songTitle": "Blackbird (Take 4)",
        "artistName": "The Beatles",
    },
    {
        "songTitle": "Blackbird (2009 Stereo Remaster)",
        "artistName": "The Beatles",
    },
    {
        "songTitle": "Blackbird (2009 Mono Remaster)",
        "artistName": "The Beatles",
    }
]
}
```

So how can I filter the results using MySQL or PHP so that only one of the Beatles "Blackbird" song is returned and not 4 of the same song with a different title?  Also, I need to do it in a way so that I still have 10 total song results to return.

Comment: Do you care _which_ of the matches from the same artist is returned?

Comment: No I dont.  Maybe I could filter out results that contain a '('

Comment: It's not the best thing to do, since grouping should really always be accompanied by an aggregate function, but you _could_ `GROUP BY artistName`.

Comment: What would the desired behavior be if The Beatles also had a song call "This Is Anti-Blackbird", which is nothing like the song "Blackbird"? Would you want both of those or only one?

Comment: If they had "This Is Anti-Blackbird" I would want both.  The problem with GROUP BY artistName is the artists that start with A are returned highest

Comment: 'If they had "This Is Anti-Blackbird" I would want both'. Then there's really no easy way to do this unless you had something like a `relatedTo` or `variantOf` column in your table where you could mark songs as being related to other songs. You could then exclude songs where there is a value in that column. Otherwise, how is the system to know which results you want and which you don't?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM song_table WHERE artistName LIKE '%blackbird%' OR 
    songTitle LIKE '%blackbird%' AND songTitle NOT LIKE '%(%' LIMIT 10` Is working pretty well I know you said it's bad but it only takes 200ms so it's fine for now and maybe I'll consider another option if I run into a problem with this solution.

Comment: That solution fails if the song is called "Fly (Blackbird Fly)" and you want it returned as a result for the "blackbird" search. Or if the title is "Rocking Blackbird (feat. Joe Awesome)". Also, I wasn't saying in my earlier comment that excluding "(" is bad (even though, for what you're tying to accomplish, it probably is bad). I was saying that using `GROUP BY` without an aggregate function isn't good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your current query and add a `GROUP BY` condition. See below

```
SELECT
*
FROM song_table
WHERE artistName LIKE '%blackbird%'
      OR songTitle LIKE '%blackbird%'
GROUP BY
    artistName
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: What would happen if The Beatles had a song named A Crow is Just a Blackbird?

Comment: Good thing they don't! I agree with @Patrick-Q, If you had a related to column. Sure you could use `NOT LIKE '%(%'` but that wouldn't work 100% of the time. Depends on the use. This goes beyond his original question.

Comment: yeah I realized that a lot of songs have '(ft. kanye west)' or somthing in the title so that's a bad solution.  I have almost a million songs in this data table though so I can't just go through and label each as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You could instead se

songTitle LIKE 'blackbird'

then you will only get the first result.

Comment: What if the song was actually called The Blackbird?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `LIKE '% text %'`, use `= 'blackbird'` in your query. As `LIKE %%` is used to match the text irrespective of what text is before or after the matching text. But when you use `=`, only matching record is return.

Comment: I think the OP does legitimately want to use the `LIKE %%` logic, they just don't want multiple variants of what we, as humans, recognize as actually the same song.

Comment: Yeah I would prefer to use '%%' logic because if a user just searches 'beatles' they will only get results if they use '%%' although not using '%%' solves the problem in my example above.